# 'MyVariable is declared but its value is never read ' When i using module type in javascript

Tags: javascript

MyVariable is connect()

```
import {connect} from './store.js'

//message Error returned when I hovered: connect is declared but its value is never read
```

And store.js gets {connect} from core.js

```
//store.js
const {attach, connect,dispatch}=createStore(withLogger(reducer))
//...
export { connect }
```

And function createStore I get it from core.js

```
//core.js
export function createStore(reducer) { 
  return { 
    connect(selector = state => state) {
      return component => (props, ...args) => 
          component(Object.assign({}, props, selector(state), ...args))
    },
   
  }
}
```

I write core.js like a library.
I open it on live server and it sends me a message:
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'MyVariable' before initialization

Actually I have fixed this error by a different way but I still want to know Where is the problem.
So hope guys help me :((

Comment: "*Cannot access 'MyVariable' before initialization*" - that hints at a circular dependency issue between your modules.

Comment: "*MyVariable is a function of object.*" - really? Please show us how you were declaring and exporting it. You can [edit] your question to include the code of both modules for a [mcve].

Comment: On the topic of minimal reproducible example, please include more of the `core.js` file, especially the part where you defined the export the `MyVariable`

Comment: Thanks you guy, I have just edited my question. I hope it 'll clearer

Comment: As @Bergi has suspected, this behavior is due to the circular dependency in your code. You are importing connect in store and store in connect. You should consider refactoring your code.